# List open web URLs

Tags: powershell

Periodically I have to go to a traders desk and explain to them why one of their applications are not starting/functioning correctly. Many times they have 20+ webpages open on their desktop.

I use this script to list the open browser session on the desktop, and it served up the PID. I am looking to view the URL of each webpage, so I can have them quickly identify which one to close, and also, as a way for them to save the URL for later. This is all I have so far - I can't get the URL of the webpage.

```
Get-Process iexplore | sort –Descending cpu
```

Comment: The code listed from user EBUser on this page seems to work: https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell_from_don_jones-24/21097/new-to-powershell-find-url  I tried it with mulptiple tabs open and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Below script return the list of URL's opened in IE.

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows() | Where { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" } | % { $_.LocationURL }
```

Hope this helps.